# Change date picker format of single form-field in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, datepicker

As you can see I have already changed the opening Date date-picker format bu,
I want to change year built format to Year(YYYY) only while keeping other form fields intact.
is it possible to do that?
or any references.

[image: form-input-date]

Comment: This example might help: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-locale

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material provides MAT_DATE_FORMATS object which is the collection of formats used by Datepicker to parse and display dates. To use custom date format we need to override MAT_DATE_FORMATS with the given formats.  Import it and provide your own date format.

```
 import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material';
```

Define a date format in a custom way as you require.

```
export const DATE_FORMAT= {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD MMM YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
  },
};
```

In @Component, add the provider

```
 providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DATE_FORMAT }
  ]
```